# Do I need any CRUD & FLS Checking for code below ? Will it pass in Appexchange Review?

Tags: apex, appexchange, crud, fls

**Note : I have done CURD & FLS for Account & Contact which I have inserted already**  i.e. **objAccount1** and **objContact1**

**Code :**

```
 //create an opp for each lead            
            Database.LeadConvert objLeadConvert = new Database.LeadConvert();
            objLeadConvert.setLeadId(myLead.Id);
            objLeadConvert.setAccountId(objAccount1.id);
            objLeadConvert.setContactId(objContact1.id);
            objLeadConvert.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(false);
            objLeadConvert.setOpportunityName(myLead.Company);            
            objLeadConvert.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

            leadsToConvert.add(objLeadConvert);            

            try{
                 **ConvertResult= Database.convertLead(objLeadConvert,true);**   // ********for this line
                 ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Confirm, 'Your Leads are Converted Successfully!'));
                 isEditable=false;
                }
                catch(Exception ex){   }
```